# Parsing Query String in node.js

Tags: javascript, http, node.js

In this "Hello World" example:

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

How can I get the parameters from the query string?

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/status?name=ryan
```

In the documentation, they mentioned:

```
node> require('url').parse('/status?name=ryan', true)
{ href: '/status?name=ryan'
, search: '?name=ryan'
, query: { name: 'ryan' }
, pathname: '/status'
}
```

But I did not understand how to use it. Could anyone explain?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can use the `parse` method from the [URL module](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html) in the request callback.

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var queryData = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

  if (queryData.name) {
    // user told us their name in the GET request, ex: http://host:8000/?name=Tom
    response.end('Hello ' + queryData.name + '\n');

  } else {
    response.end("Hello World\n");
  }
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);
```

I suggest you read the [HTTP module documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html) to get an idea of what you get in the `createServer` callback. You should also take a look at sites like http://howtonode.org/ and checkout the [Express framework](http://expressjs.com/) to get started with Node faster.

Comment: Thank you, I tested, it worked. Thanks for the links. Guess that I need to learn more :D

Comment: [This link](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/) helps me to realize that `[t]he request object is an instance of IncomingMessage`, and that `http.IncomingMessage` [has a property](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) `url`.

Comment: Is there any way to get URL params instead of query params from the IncomingMessage Object in node.js

Answer (score 36):

There's also the [QueryString module](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html)'s `parse()` method:

```
var http = require('http'),
    queryString = require('querystring');

http.createServer(function (oRequest, oResponse) {

    var oQueryParams;

    // get query params as object
    if (oRequest.url.indexOf('?') >= 0) {
        oQueryParams = queryString.parse(oRequest.url.replace(/^.*\?/, ''));

        // do stuff
        console.log(oQueryParams);
    }

    oResponse.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    oResponse.end('Hello world.');

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

Answer (score 23):

Starting with Node.js 11, the [url.parse](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) and other methods of the [Legacy URL API](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_legacy_url_api) were [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0116_legacy_url_api) (only in the documentation, at first) in favour of the [standardized](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/) [WHATWG URL API](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_the_whatwg_url_api). The new API does not offer parsing the query string into an object. That can be achieved using tthe [querystring.parse](https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options) method:

```js
// Load modules to create an http server, parse a URL and parse a URL query.
const http = require('http');
const { URL } = require('url');
const { parse: parseQuery } = require('querystring');

// Provide the origin for relative URLs sent to Node.js requests.
const serverOrigin = 'http://localhost:8000';

// Configure our HTTP server to respond to all requests with a greeting.
const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
  // Parse the request URL. Relative URLs require an origin explicitly.
  const url = new URL(request.url, serverOrigin);
  // Parse the URL query. The leading '?' has to be removed before this.
  const query = parseQuery(url.search.substr(1));
  response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  response.end(`Hello, ${query.name}!\n`);
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1.
server.listen(8000);

// Print a friendly message on the terminal.
console.log(`Server running at ${serverOrigin}/`);
```

If you run the script above, you can test the server response like this, for example:

```sh
curl -q http://localhost:8000/status?name=ryan
Hello, ryan!
```

Answer (score 9):

```
require('url').parse('/status?name=ryan', {parseQueryString: true}).query
```

returns

```
{ name: 'ryan' }
```

ref: https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_urlobject_query

Answer (score 7):

`node -v` **v9.10.1**

If you try to console log query object directly you will get error `TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value`

So I would suggest use `JSON.stringify`

```
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    const parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);

    const path = parsedUrl.pathname, query = parsedUrl.query;
    const method = req.method;

    res.end("hello world\n");

    console.log(`Request received on: ${path} + method: ${method} + query: 
    ${JSON.stringify(query)}`);
    console.log('query: ', query);
  });


  server.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server running at port 3000"));
```

So doing `curl http://localhost:3000/foo\?fizz\=buzz` will return `Request received on: /foo + method: GET + query: {"fizz":"buzz"}`

Comment: This should be moved to top. As of 2018 end, this answer solves OP's issue exactly

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get query params without require'ing any modules:

```
// ...
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

  const requestUrl = new URL(request.url, `http://${request.headers.host}`);
  // Note that searcParams is not a simple JS object.
  // So to get parameter value by its name one should use access methods:
  const nameValue = requestUrl.searchParams.get('name');

  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});    
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});
// ...
```

See [http.IncomingMessage.url](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/http.html#messageurl) and [URLSearchParams](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/url.html#class-urlsearchparams) for details.