# How to convert string to JSON in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, parameters

How do we convert the following parameter string to JSON using node.

`"token=1234&team_id=TADAS&team_domain=testddomain&channel_id=AVC"`

The expected output is 
`{ "token":1234, "team_id":"TADAS","team_domain":"testddomain","channel_id":"AVC"}`

Tried JSON.parse, not working - `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: This is likely a result of invalid JSON as `JSON.parse` is how you would achieve this in Node.

Comment: You can't because this is not a valid JSON.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590042/parsing-query-string-in-node-js

Comment: your question may be already answered here : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)

Comment: You could use [Node's `URL` module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use querystring library of node js

```
var qs = require("querystring")
var json = qs.parse("token=1234&team_id=TADAS&team_domain=testddomain&channel_id=AVC")
```

then the output is like this

```
{ "token":1234, "team_id":"TADAS","team_domain":"testddomain","channel_id":"AVC"}
```

You can refer this link 
https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options

Answer (score 8):

Since no answers here are using native, URL-oriented solutions, here's my version.

You can use [Node's URL module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) ([which also works in the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)) like so :

```js
const queryString = "token=1234&team_id=TADAS&team_domain=testddomain&channel_id=AVC";
const params = new URLSearchParams(queryString);

const paramObject = Object.fromEntries(params.entries());
    
console.log(paramObject);
```

Also, instead of building the object, you can simply use the `get` function like this :

```
const token = params.get("token") // Returns "1234"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [query-string package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string).

Usage:

```
const qs = require('query-string');

const query = "token=1234&team_id=TADAS&team_domain=testddomain&channel_id=AVC";

const parsedObject = qs.parse(query);
console.log(parsedObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that `query-string` dependency is just what you need :) https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string

The `parse` function takes a query string as parameter and returns a clean JS object.

Comment: You should give a code example instead of just a link to the package.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `split` and `reduce`.

```js
const query = "token=1234&team_id=TADAS&team_domain=testddomain&channel_id=AVC"

const json = query.split('&').reduce((acc, i) => {
  const [key, value] = i.split('=')
  acc[key] = value

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(json)
```